# 気力がつきかけていた: What meaning does かける have here? And which つき is this?

Tags: compound-verbs

> 頭のどこかで諦めてしまっている。体に力が入らず、何より**気力がつきかけていた**。

I'm not sure how to interpret the meaning of かける in this sentence. What meaning does it have here?

Also, is this つき **尽き** or **付き?**

Comment: [Definition #23 at EDICT](http://www.edrdg.org/jmdictdb/cgi-bin/entr.py?svc=jmdict&sid=&q=1207610) - "to be about to...". I think we have a duplicate of this somewhere.

Comment: @virmaior You think so? This looks to me like 尽きる "to run out"...

Comment: Context: 頭のどこかで諦めてしまっている。体に力が入らず、何より気力がつきかけていた。

Comment: @senshin it's not the first time I've been wrong! Thanks for the correction. That does make much better sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's 尽き

かける means almost

Example:

> 終わりかけた
>
> (I) almost finished